# Counting Words in a Column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a DataFrames like shown below:

```
DF1 =

 sID   token     A  B  C  D
  10    I am     a  f  g  h
  10    here     a  g  g  h
  10    whats    a  h  g  h
  10    going    a  o  g  h
  10    on       a  j  g  h
  10    .        a  f  g  h
  11    I am     a  f  g  h
  11    foo bar  a  f  g  h
  12    You are  a  f  g  h
  ...
```

The columns (A-D) don't matter regarding this task. Is there a way to add a counter column which counts the words (delimited by white space) to the DataFrame. That column should start counting the amount of tokens for each `sID`. Meaning it resets every time the value of `sID` changes.

Usually I would just use `DF.groupby("sID").cumcount()` but this only counts the amount of rows for each `sID`.

The result should look like this:

```
DF2 =

 sID   token     A  B  C  D   Counter
  10    I am     a  f  g  h    0 1
  10    here     a  g  g  h    2
  10    whats    a  h  g  h    3
  10    going    a  o  g  h    4
  10    on       a  j  g  h    5
  10    .        a  f  g  h    6
  11    I am     a  f  g  h    0 1
  11    foo bar  a  f  g  h    2 3
  12    You are  a  f  g  h    0 1
  ...
```

Comment: Why is foo 2 and bar 3? I thought here is 2 and whats is 3 in your example. And any attempt from your side? Why did it fail?

Comment: @Mr.T I think the counter restarts per `sID`. Thus, for `sID` 11 we have 'I' (0), 'am' (1), 'foo' (2) and 'bar' (3).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using `groupby("sID").cumcount()` you need to do some manipulation to keep wich row the words, once split, they belongs to. So, you can create your column 'Counter' like this:

```
df['Counter']= (df.set_index('sID',append=True)['token']
                  .str.split(' ',expand=True).stack()
                  .groupby('sID').cumcount()
                  .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(i) for i in x])))
```

and you get the expected output

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` + `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, count

df = pd.DataFrame({'sID': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12],
                   'token': ['I am', 'here', 'whats', 'going',
                             'on', '.', 'I am', 'foo bar', 'You are']})

def counter(df):
    for k, g in df.groupby('sID')['token']:
        c = count()
        lens = g.str.split().map(len)
        yield [' '.join([str(next(c)) for _ in range(n)]) for n in lens]

df['Counts'] = list(chain.from_iterable(counter(df)))
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

   sID    token Counts
0   10     I am    0 1
1   10     here      2
2   10    whats      3
3   10    going      4
4   10       on      5
5   10        .      6
6   11     I am    0 1
7   11  foo bar    2 3
8   12  You are    0 1
```

**Explanation**

- Initialise an `itertools.count` counter for each group.
- Split by whitespace and count number of words via `str.split` and `len`.
- Use a nested list comprehension for each group to recover counts.
- Chain result using `itertools.chain`.